# Dual form of $L_1$ norm approximation as a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, linear-approximation

According to my [text](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/138696/Abdelmalek,_Malek_-_Numerical_Linear_Approximation_in_C.pdf):

Given an overdetermined system, the residual vector is:

$$\textbf{r} = \textbf{Ca} - \textbf{f}$$

The $L_1$ norm approximation seeks to minimize the residual **r**:

$$\text{minimize Z} = \sum_{n=1}^{n}|r_i|$$

[image]

My question is how is the dual form derived? And where does $C^Tw$ = 0 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primal problem is

min Z=$\sum_{i=1}^n u_i+\sum_{i=1}^n v_i$

$\textbf{Ca-u+v}=\textbf{f}$

There is no term with $a_j$ in the objective function. Thus the RHS of the corresponding dual constraint is equal to zero. And $a_j$ is not restricted. It follows that the corresponding dual constraint is an equality. $\textbf w$ is the vector for the dual variables. Regarding all this information the constraint of the dual form is

$C^Tw=0$

Comment: Why is $w_i$ between -1 and 1?

Comment: The primal problem is a minimizing problem. Then if the primal variable is $\geq 0$ then the corresponding dual constraint has a $\leq$ sign.  $u_i$ has a (positive) $1$ as a coefficient in the objective function and every $u_i$ at the constraint has  a (negative) $-1$ as a coefficient at the constraint.   Now we look at the primal form in a vertically way we see that $-w_i\leq 1\Rightarrow w_i\geq -1$.  And the coefficients of  $v_i$  are (positive) 1 either at the objective function or at the constraint. Thus we have $w_i\leq 1 $